# Installshield 2015 professional, readme not configurable

Tags: installshield

I can't find a way to enable the readme checkbox on the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog.

After Googling, many people refer to the dialog having a property that allows you to enable the read me option.

These are the only properties I have:

[image]

Clearly the dialog also comes with a readme checkbox and label:

[image]

This control also has a show condition set to :

> SHOWLAUNCHREADME="-1"  And READMEFILETOLAUNCHATEND     <> "" And NOT
>   Installed      And NOT ISENABLEDWUSFINISHDIALOG

So the next thing to check is the value of that property, only they do not exist. So I've created them....

Now the readme boxes show up,

But still the readme file won't launch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple setting in the General Information section of your InstallShield project. Not sure why you need to go through all this, once specifing the 'Read Me' field it works well out-of-the-box (well, at least in the sample project I tried...).
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/IHelpPropReadme.htm

Edit: I am using InstallShield 2015 Premier, but I'm pretty sure it works just as well in Professional.